# In app.yaml env_variables, the line feed code can not be handled

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I want to set the string include line feed code to envinronment variables.
So, I set the following app.yaml.

```
env_variables:
  PARAM1: "aaa\nbbb"
```

In my local env (Mac OSX), appengine golang application get the collect data.

```
aaa
bbb
```

But, I uploaded to Standard GAE environment, application get only "aaa".

Should I do any other settings?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the yaml parser between the 2 environments is slightly different.

Does it work if you try switch to one of these multiline string formats for yaml?

[In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines)

This answer looks promising for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15365296/4458510

Comment: Thanks! I try to block format.

But the same result.... On GAE, only one line is read...

Is there any restriction at GAE yaml parser?